# Regex help need to match an ampersand OR and end of string

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to create a regex to match part of a URL
The possible URLs might be

> www.mysite.com?userid=123xy
>
> www.mysite.com?userid=123x&username=joe
>
> www.mysite.com?tag=xyz&userid=1ww45
>
> www.mysite.com?tag=xyz&userid=1g3x5&username=joe

I'm trying to match the `userid=123456`

So far I have

```
Dim r As New Regex("[&?]userID.*[?&]")
Debug.WriteLine(r.Match(strUrl))
```

But this is only matching lines 2 and 4.
Can anyone help?

Comment: `[?&]` => `(&|$)`, but most languages have more robust url & parameter parsing you could perhaps use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?<=[?&]userid=)[^&#\s]*`

Output:

```
123xy 
123x
1ww45
1g3x5
```

A few points:

- This works both if you are matching one URL at a time and if you have a whitespace-separated set.
- This captures the username only. It uses the non-capturing positive look-behind assertion since you only care about the username.
- The fragment part, if present, will be ignored (e.g. if the URL looked like this: `www.mysite.com?tag=xyz&userid=1ww45#top`)
- If the case of `userid` doesn't matter, use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it:
[&?]userID=[^\s&#]+

Answer (score 0):

PHP solution:

```
"/[\\?&]userid=([^&]*)/"
```

Tests:

```
$tests = [
    [
        "regex" => "/[\\?&]userid=([^&]*)/",
        "expected" => "123xy",
        "inputs" => [
            "www.mysite.com?userid=123xy",
            "www.mysite.com?userid=123xy&username=joe",
            "www.mysite.com?tag=xyz&userid=123xy",
            "www.mysite.com?tag=xyz&userid=123xy&username=joe"
        ]
    ]
];

foreach ($tests as $test) {

    $regex = $test['regex'];
    $expected = $test['expected'];

    foreach ($test['inputs'] as $input) {

        if (!preg_match($regex, $input, $match)) {
            throw new Exception("Regex '{$regex}' doesn't match for input '{$input}' or error has occured.");
        }

        $matched = $match[1];
        if ($matched !== $expected) {           
            throw new Exception("Found '{$matched}' instead of '{$expected}'.");
        }

        echo "Matched '{$matched}' in '{$input}'." . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Matched '123xy' in 'www.mysite.com?userid=123xy'.
Matched '123xy' in 'www.mysite.com?userid=123xy&username=joe'.
Matched '123xy' in 'www.mysite.com?tag=xyz&userid=123xy'.
Matched '123xy' in 'www.mysite.com?tag=xyz&userid=123xy&username=joe'.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the regex: `.*?(userid=\d+).*`

`.*?` - is a non-greedy way to express: everything that comes before `(userid=\d+)`

Python example:

```
import re

a = 'www.mysite.com?userid=12345'
b = 'www.mysite.com?userid=12345&username=joe'
mat = re.match('.*?(userid=\d+).*', a)
print mat.group(1)  # prints userid=12345

mat = re.match('.*?(userid=\d+).*', b) 
print mat.group(1) # prints userid=12345
```

Link to **[Fiddler](http://regex101.com/r/lA6vF5/3)**

Comment: @SteveGray In the question you wrote: "trying to match the userid=123456" and now in the comments (of a deleted answer) you're writing the opposite... which one is it then ? what is the expected output ?